# TSP problem in C using simple backtracking Solution

Tags: c, backtracking, traveling-salesman

I was trying to solve the travel salesman program im stuck at the recursive part of moving from one city to another.

**Sample input & output:**

```
    Please enter the roads 4X4 matrix row by row:
    0 2 -1 2
    -1 0 2 -1
    1 -1 0 2
    2 1 -1 0
    The shortest path is of length: 6
```

**Main Objective**

each number at the matrice roads[N][N] (currently N=4)
is the distance as following:
location (i,j) the number represents distance from city i to city j.
and the objective is to get from city number 0 (line 0 in matrice) through all cities back to city 0 at shortest path.

**My Solution**
Create a shell function ShortestFullPath() with all first parameters.
and seconed backtracking function short_path
 where i check stopping conditions (such as same city => 0 or no city => -1 or finished going through all cites)

A array visited is as the size of number of cities.
each city I visit, I flag the matching index in the array as true or false, and check all options in the city to other cities.

**Side Notes**

checkvisited() checks if array visited is all true;

min() checks minimun between current_path and the best path so far.

```
int ShortestFullPath(int roads[N][N])


bool visited[N];
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    visited[i] = false;
}
int shortest_path = 9999;
int current_path = 0;
int city = 0;
int j = 0; //destinaton city
visited [0] = true;
if(short_path(roads, city, j, current_path, &shortest_path, visited))
    Print(shortest_path);
else
    Print(NO_PATH);
return 0;



bool short_path(int roads[N][N], int city, int j, int current_path,
int *shortest_path, bool visited[N])
{

    if(check_visited(visited))
    {
        *(shortest_path) = min(current_path, *shortest_path);
        current_path = 0;
        return true;
    }
    if((roads[city][j] == -1) ||(roads[city][j] == 0)){
          return false;}
    if(visited[city] == true)
        return false;

    visited[city] = true;
    current_path = current_path + roads[city][j];


    for(int j =0; j< N; j++)
    {
        short_path(roads, city, j, current_path, shortest_path, visited);
    }
    visited[city] = false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: *came into a wall* - is not a valid description of a problem in this context.

Comment: Please make an [mcve]. Provide sample input, output, desired output and an explanation of what the "wall" is you have hit.

Comment: This code is really rough in terms of formatting. I've tried to clean it up a little, but it's still a big jumble.

Comment: hey guys! thank you so much for the replies!
as you see i'm only at the beginning but Ill clean it up and edit my question thanks!

Comment: I tried to clear it up .
is it better?